# How do I separate my controllers If I have nested resources? (JAVA Spring)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I'm developing a forum API in JAVA using Spring and I been refactoring my URLS so they are nested using a maximum of 2 levels.

**For example I have the following endpoints in UserPostController:**
(GET) /api/v1/users/{username}/posts
(GET) /api/v1/users/{username}/posts/{postId}
(POST) /api/v1/users/{username}/posts
(PUT) /api/v1/users/{username}/posts/{postId}
(DELETE) /api/v1/users/{username}/posts/{postId}

(The posts cannot exists if they aren't linked to an existing user)

**But I also wanted an endpoint that let me get ALL existing Posts of ALL Users so I figure I't will be something like:**
(GET) /api/v1/posts

I created another controller called **"PostController"** for that but only with that endpoint.

The problem is that I have another relationships like this one, for example between Post and Comments, and I will end up creating a lot of Controllers for the cases when I want to GET ALL CHILDRENS OF ALL PARENTS. I'm sure there is another better way.

Edit:
I also have to mention that the base path for the UserPostController is "/api/v1/users/{username}/posts".

Answer (score 0):

Your current REST-Design for basic input/output posts is well designed. If I try to give it a name I would call it the Posts-Service.

I suggest to create a second REST-Microservice for that aggregation issue (let me call it Aggregation-Service) because:

1. I think you need lower performance on the Posts-Service than on the Aggregation-Service. Because `ALL existing Posts of ALL Users` and `GET ALL CHILDRENS OF ALL PARENTS` might return hughe data and looks to be read-only. So they have different performance requirements than your `Posts-Service` and you might balance them differently.
2. I think the aggregation might have changes (i.e.: new ordering/filtering-functionality) that can be compleatly detached from the development of the `Posts-Service`. You can release changes from Aggregation-Service and Posts-Service seperatly or at least be able to make different A/B tests.
3. Posts-Service require a security-concpet. Aggregation Service might not need a security-concept.

Kind Regards

Comment: Thanks!, I forgot to mention that It's a monolith so I don't know what to do In this scenario. Because of the basepath of the UserPostController being "/api/v1/users/{username}/posts" (I fix it on the original post) I don't know where to put the "/api/v1/posts" endpoint wich does NOT have to recieve the parent id. It will be correct for example to make a DashboardController only with the "GET ALL" endpoints of every type?. I also read one example where they passed a dash as the parent Id but that doesn't seem too correct for me.

Comment: @AFrequentVisitor you are right you can not use microservices in a monolith. Ill keep this answer since others might have the same question.

Answer (score 0):

You could create such an DashboardController (your words) and create a path having so-called Matrix-Parameters. They seperate pre-questionmark-requests using the `;` as part of the URL.

Matrix parameters are designed exactly for your case but not well-accepted in the REST-Community. Anyway, this is the Matrix-Solution:

http://www.example.com/api/v1/dashboard/all;parentId=123

http://www.example.com/api/v1/dashboard/all

Comment: The idea of the DashboardController I mentioned was because of the UserPostController basepath being "/api/v1/users/{username}/posts" and the (apparently) impossibility to add the "/api/posts", wich returns all posts no matter the user, to the same controller. So I imagine this "DashboardController" having endpoints like "/api/v1/posts" or "api/v1/comments/" to get ALL childrens of these parent types because the existing controllers have to recieve parentId parameter. Sorry if I dind't explain myself very well, English is not my first language.

Comment: I'll rephrase the question if it will help. Where can I put an "/api/posts" endpoint (To get all posts no matter the user) if my existing controller have a RequestMapping (at class level) that recieves a parent identifier? ("/api/v1/users/{username}/posts") and obviously If I want to get ALL posts I dont have any parent identifier to pass in that specific case.